# Iteratively Update Lists in a Dictionary

Tags: python

I have a Web API containing data in that format:

```
[{'being': 'human', 'color': 'purple', 'age': 28},
 {'being': 'monkey', 'color': 'orange', 'age': 20},
 {'being': 'dog', 'color': 'pink', 'age': 4}]
```

I created a function to extract data out of it. The function works well, but now I want to be able to iteratively update multiple lists using the function instead of having to call the function multiple times.

```
def dataMiner(list1, colName):
    for obs in api.query('creatures')['value']:
        list1.append(obs[colName])
    return list1
```

This function ^^ extracts the data out as needed. But instead of dataMiner(being, 'being'), dataMiner(age, 'age'), etc. I created a function to iteratively update all these lists with the code below:

```
Being = []
Color = []
Age = []

listDict = {‘being’: ‘being’, ‘color’: ‘color’, ‘age’: ‘age’}

def listUpdate(listdic):
    for list1, column in listdic.items():
        list1 = []
        dataMiner(list1, column)
```

However, the lists do not get updated as anticipated. Were am I going wrong? This data is mock data, but the format is similar to the actual data.

Comment: You never modify the lists in your dict, if that was what you were expecting, or the dict itself. You modify a new list, `list1 = []` on each iteration which you seem to simply discard

Comment: Why did you write `list1 = []`?

Comment: Because the keys in listDict are all strings. I am telling listUpdate() to turn the key(s) into list(s) before putting them into dataMiner()

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: You don't have lists in a dictionary, you have dictionaries in a list.

Comment: Can you show a sample of `listdic`, and what you want the final result to be?

Comment: @Barmar listdic is a placeholder in the function. When I'm actually calling the function, I give it a dictionary with the list's name and the column names I want for dataMiner()

Comment: It's still not clear what you want this function to do. What is it supposed to update?

Comment: @Barmar lists added. I want to update the lists with each observations' data. For example, I want the 'being' list to contain values 'human, monkey, dog' so on so forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a list be a key in a dictionary.  If your keys in listdic represent variable names, you'll need to change your approach as it is generally difficult (and not a good practice) to referance variables by their names in a string (makes things unnecessarily hard).

If listdic was a list of tuples containing the actual list references, then you could approach it like this:

```
def listUpdate(listMap):
    for listRef,column in listMap:
        dataMiner(listRef,column)
```

Usage:

```
being = list()
color = list()
age   = list()
lists = [ (being,‘being’), (color,‘color’) (age,‘age’) ]

listUpdate(lists)

print(being) # ['human', 'monkey', 'dog']
print(color) # ['purple', 'orange', 'pink']
print(age)   # [28, 20, 4]
```

You could also invert the column name and list references in listdic if you must to use a dictionary (assuming each column only has one target list to update):

```
def listUpdate(listMap):
    for column,listRef in listMap:
        dataMiner(listRef,column)
```

Usage:

```
being   = list()
color   = list()
age     = list()
listdic = { ‘being’:being, ‘color’:color, ‘age’:age }

listUpdate(listdic)
```

Comment: Pure Genius! Thank you very much for your pointers and guidance!! I've been at this for a 8 days.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in a dictionary containing the resulting lists.

```
def listUpdate(resultdict):
    for column, list1 in resultdict.items():
        dataMiner(list1, column)

listUpdate({'being': Being, 'color': Color, 'age': Age})
```